# Set RadComboBox value from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have a RadCombobox in a user control and I am trying to set the value to null or 0 from Javascript. The following code doesn't work. But it's not showing any error also.

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
    var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        var ddl = document.getElementById('ctl00_plh1_Test1_Dropdown2_RadComboBox1_DropDown');
        ddl.selectedIndex = 0;

}

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Dropdown1" runat="server" 
                             NoWrap="true" Width="250" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
                            <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>



<uc2:RadComboBox ID="Dropdown2" runat="server" DdlAutoWidth="true"></uc2:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: try this var ddl = document.getElementById('maincontent_RadcomboBox'); maincontent should be the  ID of the UserControl

Comment: I was able to find the control using my code but selectedIndex is not working.

Comment: your dropdown does not contain any item, then how you are setting it's index ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
var mycombobox = $find("<%= MyUserControl.FindControl("RadComboBox1").ClientID %>");
```

or

```
var mycombobox = $find("<%= RadComboBox1").ClientID %>");

mycombobox.clearSelection();
```

You might need this

```
<rad:RadScriptBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock">
   <script type="text/javascript">

   </script>
</rad:RadScriptBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the `RadComboBox` that will trigger the `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged` event will have 2 or more `RadCombBoxItem`s, otherwise the event will never be fired as the selected index can never change.

When the event fires, you must get a reference to the `RadComboBox` control inside your `UserControl`. To set it's SelectedIndex property to 0 you call the `set_selectedIndex()` function on the client-side control. Keep in mind that this only sets the SelectedIndex, and does not update the text in the input field of the `RadComboBox`. If you want to clear that out as well you must call the client-side control's `set_text()` function.

```
function onComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(s, e) {
    var ctrl = '<%= Dropdown2.FindControl("RadComboBox1").ClientID %>';
    if (ctrl) {
        ctrl.set_selectedIndex(0);
        ctrl.set_text('');
    } 
}
```

Please refer to the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html) on Telerik's website for more information regarding the JavaScript API for the RadCombBox control.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to set to `0` or `null` the selected value or selected index?
Try this for the selected value:

```
$find("<%=ctl00_plh1_Test1_Dropdown2_RadComboBox1_DropDown.ClientID%>").set_text("0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the selected value in javascript:

```
var SelectdVal=1;
$find("<%= YourRadComboBox.ClientID %>").findItemByValue(SelectdVal).select();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var radComboBox = <%=YourComboBox.ClientID %>;  

radComboBox.SetValue("someValue");
```